# ANTLR4 parsing subrules

Tags: java, antlr4, text-parsing

I have a grammar that works fine when parsing in one pass (entire file).

Now I wish to break the parsing up into components.  And run the parser on subrules.  I ran into an issue I assume others parsing subrules will see with the following rule:

```
thing   :   LABEL? THING  THINGDATA thingClause?
            //{System.out.println("G4 Lexer/parser thing encountered");}
        ;
...
thingClause : ',' ID ( ',' ID)?
            ;
```

When the above rule is parsed from a top level start rule which parses to EOF everything works fine.   When parsed as a sub-rule (not parse to EOF) the parser gets upset when there is no thing clause, as it is expecting to see EITHER a "," character or an EOF character.

line 8:0 mismatched input '%' expecting {, ','}

When I parse to EOF, the % gets correctly parsed into another "thing" component, because the top level rule looks for:

```
  toprule :  thing+
          |  endOfThingsTokens
          ;
```

And endOfThingsTokens occurs before EOF... so I expect this is why the top level rule works.

For parsing the subrule, I want the ANTLR4 parser to accept or ignore the % token and say "OK we aren't seeing a thingClause", then reset the token stream so the next thing object can be parsed by a different instance of the parser.

In this specific case I could change the lexer to pass newlines to the parser, which I currently skip in the lexer grammar. That would require lots of other changes to accept newlines in the token stream which are currently not needed.

Essentially I need some way to make the rule have a "end of record" token.  But I was wondering if there was some way to solve this with a semantic predicate rule.

something like:

```
    thing   :   { if comma before %}? LABEL? THING  THINGDATA thingClause?
            | LABEL? THING THINGDATA
            ;
    ...

    thingClause : ',' ID ( ',' ID)?
            ;
```

The above predicate pseudo code would hide the optional thingClause? if it won't be satisfied so that the parser would stop after parsing one "thing" without looking for a specific "end of thing" token (i.e. newline).

If I solve this I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The parser will (effectively) look-ahead in the token stream to determine if the current rule can be satisfied. The corresponding tokens are then consumed. If any look-ahead tokens remain unconsumed, the parser looks for another rule against which to consume these and additional look-ahead tokens.

The `thingClause?` element, when not matched, will result in unconsumed tokens in the parser. Hence the error you are seeing.

The parser look-ahead is data dependent. Meaning that the evaluation of the elements of a rule can easily read into the parser more tokens than the current rule could possibly consume.

While a predicate could help, it will not make the problem deterministic. That is, even if the parser matches the non-predicated alt, it may well have read more tokens into the parser than can be consumed by that alt.

The only way to avoid this non-determinism would be to pre-inject `<EOF>` tokens into the token stream at the sub-rule boundaries.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been thinking about how to create a generic method for pre-injecting EOF.  I've looked at the TokenReWriter, but that doesn't seem to work how I wanted to use it, as the examples I've seen of it are invoked after parsing the original token stream.  But there appears to be enough rope for me to create a custom token stream that injects EOF tokens where I might want them.

Comment: Sorry, did not intend to encourage you. While theoretically possible, it is a terribly impractical approach. The far better choice would be to identify and solve the problem preventing you from using a simple/standard Antlr implementation.

Comment: @RossYoungblood you can of course create a `thingStandalone` rule with an EOF at the end (which calls your `thing` rule) if you want to match only this subrule.

Comment: @GRosenberg  The simple/standard ANTLR implementation is a memory hog.  I'm going to increase VR. where I'm charged by Mem*second config.  The parse subrule technique works and the memory footprint is 10% of the "parse to EOF".  So while I agree it's likely impractical, I'm still beating the dead horse to see if it will get me across the finish line, along with investigating other approaches.

Comment: @Mike won't the EOF force the parser to seek to EOF? and any tokens between the end of recognized chars in my subrule and EOF be considered syntax errors? What I'm attempting is to break up a HUGE (>1Gb) input stream into subfiles automatically.   Effectively what I'm seeking is to convert my LISTENER class into a class that operates like embedded parse rule actions.  i.e. run the listener classes when encountering the rule, but don't generate a parse tree.  My understanding is that the only way to call listeners is to gen a huge parse tree and walk it. Inefficient for large files/streams.